# Modify linux protocol table

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ip

For some reason I need to change linux protocol table. For example I want to linux recognize protocol 1 as ipv4 (protocol 4) or protocol 47 to l2tp . 
Does anyone know how to change this inside linux kernel or preferably in /sys folder, So my client send protocol tcp as an icmp protocol and in other side it receive icmp and recognize it as tcp.
thanks,

Comment: You really should explain what is your reason.... I tend to believe you are wrong in wanting to do that... The whole idea of networking is compatibility and interoperability, and you lose both... It would be better to design your own protocol properly (with its unique number). And you could lose any program coded in non-C compatible language (e.g. Ocaml).

Comment: Are you trying to use this to sneak traffic past firewalls that might inspect TCP/UDP traffic? I would strongly recommend against doing that (no matter how noble or justified the motives): It will probably not work, and it doesn't provide any kind of reliable security.

Comment: This might be better done as an iptables thing. It sounds like a job for the mangle table. You probably need to write your own module.

Comment: Basile: In my countries accessing other web site are restricted and we need to use vpn to access sites such as facebook. Recently everty packet containing protocol gre ,l2tp and some other filtered in gateway.
I'm examining new way to this problem.

Comment: Zan: I didn't find any solution related to protocol change in iptables.  I will open new topic for this. Please guide me with your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocol numbers are defined in `include/uapi/linux/in.h`. Exercise great caution when changing stuff there, you will make your OS incompatible with practically everything else there is out there.

edit: Watch out for drivers that blatantly ignore the value of `IPPROTO_TCP` in favor of hardcoded values... I just found this 'gem' in `drivers/infiniband/hw/nes/nes_cm.c`:

```
451     iph->protocol = 0x06;   /* IPPROTO_TCP */
```